# How make a folder hidden and locked in Windows

Tags: windows-7

I am using Windows 7. I have a folder named `Progs` and there are lot of files and folders in it. If someone tries to access this folder `Progs`, no folder should be visible to anyone, and if someone tries to delete `Progs` they should not be able to do that.

In older versions of Windows there was an option to lock the folder using `ren` and `ALT` keys, but I don't think it's working in Windows XP now.

I don't to secure the files with third party software. I just want to hide and lock the folder in its place.

Comment: You should use ACLs to do this instead. Besides, other users shouldn’t be able to access files in your user profile.

Comment: i cant use ACL as other users knows my password is shared among other users

Comment: If all the users share the same account, you can’t have any security.

Comment: Don't really see the point to this question. If you wanna keep people out of certain rooms in your house you don't give them a key to your house and ask for ways to secure the rooms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is so simple:

```
attrib +R +H Progs
```

Comment: Note that this will only deter inexperienced users. It is simple to circumvent or undo. Maybe you can do something with Alternate Data Streams like http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-hide-data-in-a-secret-text-file-compartment/